# Java importing packages

Tags: java, import

I have a program in my desktop that I want to run (structure in the url), but when I do compile, with
`\code\nlp\assignments\parsing\javac PCFGParserTester.java` 
I get:

```
PCFGParserTester.java:6: error: package nlp.io does not exist
import nlp.io.PennTreebankReader;
         ^
PCFGParserTester.java:7: error: package nlp.ling does not exist
import nlp.ling.Tree;
           ^
PCFGParserTester.java:8: error: package nlp.ling does not exist
import nlp.ling.Trees;
           ^
PCFGParserTester.java:9: error: package nlp.parser does not exist
import nlp.parser.EnglishPennTreebankParseEvaluator;
```

how do I get my program to correctly import my packages?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to be in the `\code` directory and compile with:

```
javac nlp\assignments\parsing\PCFGParserTest.java
```

(And you should have a package declaration of `package nlp.assignments.parsing;` to match the position in the directory structure.)

That way `javac` will look for the other classes appropriately.

Alternatively, and rather more simply, you could use an IDE such as Eclipse or NetBeans, and it would take care of all this for you - you'd just specify the `code` directory as a source directory, and all would be well.